# In ggplot2, how do I group geom_smooth on facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot time trends across facets and failing at adding `geom_smooth` correctly.

Doing this:

```
economics_mod <- economics_long %>% 
  mutate(type = variable) %>% 
  mutate(type = recode(type, `pce` = "1", `pop` = "1", .default = "2"))

ggplot(economics_mod, aes(date, value01, group = variable)) +
  geom_path() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ type, ncol = 1) +
  geom_smooth()
```

Gets me here:

[image]

Problem is I would like to have one smotthed line per facet, not a series of data.

I tried tinkering with different set ups of `aes` for `path` and `smooth` but none gives any results. Where is the problem?

Update: @mikeck and @Marius solution solves the issue:

```
library(Matrix)
ggplot(economics_mod, aes(date, value01)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = variable)) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ type, ncol = 1) +
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Try putting the `group` aesthetic in `geom_path(aes())` rather than in `ggplot()`. This will make it so that `geom_smooth()` doesn't use `group`.

Comment: Re: the error: just `install.packages("Matrix")` and try again. It's a pretty common dependency I think.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, should have known better ;) That solved the problem.